# datainputstream missing bytes in.read(b)

Tags: java, byte, datainputstream

I'm trying to write a program which acts as a server that will read bytes from a client that is written in PHP - sends request via socket (which i cannot recode due to policy) Here is the server code:
The server runs in: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.2 (Santiago)

```
public void run() {
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        serverSocket.setSoTimeout(0);            

        while(!isInterrupted) {
            try {                    
                Socket server = serverSocket.accept();

                LOG.info("Request received from : " + server.getRemoteSocketAddress());                    
                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(server.getInputStream());
                // DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(
                //        new BufferedInputStream(server.getInputStream(), 10000));  

                byte[] bytes = new byte[10000];

                int byteDupLength = in.read(t_bytes);                    
                // in.readFully(bytes); // I tried this but to no avail
                // int byteDupLength = bytes.length;

                LOG.info(byteDupLength);                    
                byte[] byteDup = new byte[byteDupLength];                    
                System.arraycopy(bytes, 4, byteDup, 0, byteDupLength);

                // FOR INFORMATION ONLY
                /*for (byte b : byteDup){                        
                    LOG.info(b);

                }*/
                ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteDup);
                LOG.info(buffer);

                forwardRequest(byteDup);
                server.close();
            }
            catch(SocketTimeoutException s) {
                LOG.error("Socket timed out!", s);
                break;
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                LOG.error("IOException:", e);
                break;
            }
        } 
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) {
        LOG.error("Server socket is null", ex);
    }
    LOG.fatal("ReceiverEngine interrupted!");
}
```

I encountered a problem when the client sends request consisting of 4948 bytes. The only bytes the server can read is 2090.
Another thing that seems a mystery to me is that, when I run the server via Netbeans in my local (which is a Windows 7 Pro), it works as expected. I dont know what is wrong. Please help.. :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. TCP is a byte stream protocol.
2. The `read()` method isn't guaranteed to fill the buffer.

Therefore if you don't receive the expected number of bytes in a single read, you have to loop until you do receive them.

`readFully()` would have worked if the buffer size agreed with the size of what was sent. In your case you specified a buffer of 10,000 bytes, which weren't sent, so it would have blocked waiting for the other 10000-4948 bytes.